# Iterating objects with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

So, I am learning out backbone.js and are currently iterating over some models in a view with the below example. The first snippet works, when the other underscore.js-based one doesn't. Why?

```
// 1: Working
this.collection.each(function(model){ console.log(model.get("description")); });

// 2: Not working       
_.each(this.collection, function(model){ console.log(model.get("description")); });
```

What am I doing wrong, as I can't see it by myself?

Comment: Does *anything* happen? Are there errors in the console?

Comment: No. #2 executes silently without any output to the console.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`this.collection` is an instance while `this.collection.each` is a method that iterates the proper object under the covers which is the `.models` property of a collection instance.

With this said you can try:

```
_.each(this.collection.models, function(model){ console.log(model.get("description")); });
```

Which is completely pointless as `this.collection.each` is a function that does similar to:

```
function(){
return _.each.apply( _, [this.models].concat( [].slice.call( arguments ) ) );
}
```

So you might as well use `this.collection.each` ;P

Comment: Thanks for your explanation of why it didn't work along with the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Also, you could try...

```
_.each(this.collection.models, function(model){
    console.log(model.get("description"));
});
```