# "this.collection.each is not a function". Shouldn't it simply say "each"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I really have a two part question.

The console is telling me:  "TypeError: this.collection.each is not a function"

In the short-term I would love to know why my code isn't working.

In the long term I am more interested in knowing why it is not telling me that "each" is not a function, since that is the method I am trying to call.

P.S. I have confirmed that JQuery is loading correctly, and before this code loads, so that is not the problem.

The pertinent javascript is:

```
$(function(){

var items = [
        { name: 'Abe Lincoln', details: 'Is he that guy from that new reality show?'},
        { name: 'Captain Planet', details: 'He is our hero'},
        { name: 'Karthus', details: 'Press R'},
        { name: 'Your Mom', details: 'She misses me'},
        { name: 'Teddy Roosevelt', details: 'Makes the most interesting man in the world look boring'}
    ];

    var itemsCollectionView = new ListView({collection: items});
    Backbone.history.start();
});

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#the-list',

    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
            this.collection.each(function(model){
            this.addOne(model);
        }, this);
    },

    //create an itemview for a model, and add it to the list view
    addOne:function(model){
        var itemView = new ItemView({model: model});
        this.$el.append(itemView.render().el);
    }
});
```

Comment: It’s being helpful by telling you the entire “path”. What’s the problem? (Also, try `forEach`.)

Comment: Thanks, forEach works. I'll have to do a bit of research to learn why that worked, but not each. Perhaps the version of JQuery I am using? Additionally, thanks for filling me in on why the console works that way. Wasn't sure if it was because it was something I did wrong to make the browser interpret the entire thing as a method, or if it was simply to help me find my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.collection.each` is fine to use with Backbone, the problem is that you are not passing an actual Backbone collection to the instance of ItemView, but simply an array. You would need something like the following:

```
var itemsCollection = new ItemsCollection(items), // substitute your collection variable
    itemsCollectionView = new ListView({ collection: itemsCollection });
```

Also, I tried running your code on Backbone 1.0.0 and jQuery 1.10.1 and I get

```
   TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'each'
```

Comment: For whatever reason switching to forEach was able to fix the particular error. Which allowed me to discover the problem that you had foreseen. Thanks for the preemptive help. This was quite helpful in fixing my next problem.

Comment: If you found my answer suitable, can you accept the answer? Thanks!

Comment: @user1937279: Arrays have a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

Comment: Sure, but the JQuery documentation mentions .each() should work for "both objects and arrays". http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Oh... would it be because my collection is not a jquery object?

Comment: It is using the Underscore .each, see this [SO answer for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421238/iterating-objects-with-underscore-js).

Comment: @user1937279: `$.each` is called as `$.each(array, ...)`, not `array.each(...)`, same with Underscore's [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) (except that Underscore's can also be called as `_(array).each(...)`). It is Underscore's `each` that is [mixed into Backbone collections](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods).